# WildFly 31.0.0.Final datasource config fails with MySQL driver not found (as module) when launched from IntelliJ

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly, mysql-connector

I think I've done this dozens of times. Install a local WildFly, add a MySQL driver as module for WildFly to connect to a local DB instance. This is for WildFly 31.0.0.Final.

Here's the `standalone.xml`:

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:7.1">
        <datasources>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" statistics-enabled="${wildfly.datasources.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}">
                <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MODE=${wildfly.h2.compatibility.mode:REGULAR}</connection-url>
                <driver>h2</driver>
                <security user-name="sa" password="sa"/>
            </datasource>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/BBStatsDS" pool-name="BBStatsDS">
                <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bbstats</connection-url>
                <driver>mysql</driver>
                <security user-name="root" password="yippieyahey"/>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
                <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
                    <driver-class>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                    <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
    </subsystem>
```

I installed the MySQL connector driver to WildFly under `com/mysql/main`:

[image]

`module.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  ~ Copyright The WildFly Authors
  ~ SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
  -->
<module name="com.mysql" xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.9">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar" />
    </resources>
    
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api "/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

I double-checked the driver in the admin console, which seems to be OK:

[image]

But when I launch the server (from IntelliJ), I get:

```
09:49:31,266 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "BBStatsDS")
]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "service jboss.data-source.\"jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.BBStatsDS\" is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql]",
        "service jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasources/BBStatsDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql]"
    ]
}
09:49:31,267 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "BBStatsDS")
]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql",
        "jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql"
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "service jboss.data-source.\"jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.BBStatsDS\" is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql]",
        "service jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasources/BBStatsDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql]",
        "service jboss.data-source.\"jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.BBStatsDS\" is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql]"
    ]
}
09:49:31,272 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql (missing) dependents: [service jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasources/BBStatsDS, service jboss.data-source."jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.BBStatsDS"] 
WFLYCTL0448: 2 additional services are down due to their dependencies being missing or failed
```

**EDIT:**

Launching via `standalone.sh` doesn't make any difference from what I see:

[image]

**Q:**

What's wrong?

Is the server too new for the driver?

Comment: can you add pom.xml file

Comment: Just a couple minor things. The module should just be under the `modules/com/mysql/main` directory. However, that's not a critical issue, just a best practice. The `javax.api` module is deprecated and the `javax.transaction.api` module should be `jakarta.transaction.api`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding mysql driver as a module try adding to your pom file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.33</version>
</dependency>
```

I also suggest defining datasource with @DataSourceDefinition annotation that way your code will be Application server agnostic and it is lot easier if you work with Docker. configuration as code.

```
import jakarta.annotation.sql.DataSourceDefinition;
import jakarta.ejb.Singleton;

@Singleton
@DataSourceDefinition(
    name = "java:app/deneme2DS",
    className = "org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource",
    url = "jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1",
    user = "sa",
    password = "sa"
)
public class DataSourceConfig {

    // This class can be empty, as it only serves to define the DataSource
    // The DataSource will be automatically registered when this class is loaded

}
```

Finally remove the driver and datasource definitions from your standalone.xml and also remove the MySQL driver JAR from the modules dir.

Comment: FYI: the XML equivalent is `<data-source>` in `web.xml` and was already available since Servlet 3.0.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC i was aware of that but putting datasource in web.xml  but is kind of weird for me it breaks single responsibility principle, web.xml should be only for servlet configuration i think. by the way i have a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77940005/jboss-jca-common-api-validator-validateexception-ij010075-the-resource-adapter do you have any guesses for that?

Answer (score 1):

I tested the following locally and this worked for me. Note I just used a docker version of MySQL.

```
module add --name=com.mysql --resources=~/Downloads/mysql-connector-j-8.3.0/mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar --dependencies=java.se,java.logging,javax.sql.api,jakarta.transaction.api
/subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=mysql:add(driver-name=mysql, driver-module-name=com.mysql)
/subsystem=datasources/data-source=mysql:add(driver-name=mysql, jndi-name="java:jboss/jdbc/BBStatsDS", enabled=true, connection-url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", user-name=testuser, password=testpassword)
```

What the above does is uses CLI to add the module, add the driver and configure a data-source. When I test the data-source, it seems to work:

```
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=datasources/data-source=mysql:test-connection-in-pool
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => [true]
}
```

Comment: How do you know the "new" dependencies? I did not find any examples out there with the dependencies you posted.

Comment: I don't really think the dependencies are the issue, I was just more letting you know. We are working on some guides, but I don't see any about Data Sources yet, https://www.wildfly.org/guides/. Note too that we try not to change the module dependencies often if at all. The javax -> jakarta namespace change is hopefully an anomaly.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer in the WildFly Google groups here https://groups.google.com/g/wildfly/c/CBSWKgWL5xo, where the best approach is to actually not install the MySQL driver as a module at all.

Put this into your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.33</version>
</dependency>
```

Define the data source within your application code:

```
import jakarta.annotation.sql.DataSourceDefinition;
import jakarta.ejb.Singleton;

@Singleton
@DataSourceDefinition(
    name = "java:jboss/datasources/YourDataSourceDS",
    className = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlXADataSource",
    url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourbdname",
    user = "lala",
    password = "lalala"
)
public class DataSourceConfig {

    // this class can be empty, as it only serves to define the data source
    // the data source will be automatically registered when this class is loaded

}
```

Remove the driver and datasource definitions from your `standalone.xml` and also remove the MySQL driver JAR from the modules dir.

Kudos go out to https://stackoverflow.com/users/5964741/ebuzer-taha-kanat

If he still wants to reply to this, I will accept his answer. You may copy my answer (if you're reading this) and I will delete my own answer then (sorry for the chat).

Comment: i have posted the answer thanks