# jboss.jca.common.api.validator.ValidateException: IJ010075: The resource adapter metadata must contain either an outbound or inbound configuration

Tags: wildfly, java-ee-7, datanucleus, jca

i'm trying to deploy a jdo resource adapter to wildfly 10 with this code: https://github.com/urbandroid/datanucleus-jca-adapter
java:/TestDS datasource deployed to server resource adapter must use this datasource.

I'm not sure what to put on inbound or outbound section it is a jdo adapter which is a ORM tool which needs to stand between my code and datasource.

I'm getting error below can you help me?

```
1:55:12,652 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."datanucleus-jdo-jca-6.0.6.rar".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."datanucleus-jdo-jca-6.0.6.rar".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "datanucleus-jdo-jca-6.0.6.rar"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:154)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: org.jboss.jca.common.api.validator.ValidateException: IJ010075: The resource adapter metadata must contain either an outbound or inbound configuration
    at org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.ra.processors.ParsedRaDeploymentProcessor.process(ParsedRaDeploymentProcessor.java:216)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.ra.processors.ParsedRaDeploymentProcessor.deploy(ParsedRaDeploymentProcessor.java:127)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.jboss.jca.common.api.validator.ValidateException: IJ010075: The resource adapter metadata must contain either an outbound or inbound configuration
    at org.jboss.jca.common.metadata.spec.ResourceAdapterImpl.validate(ResourceAdapterImpl.java:228)
    at org.jboss.jca.common.metadata.spec.ConnectorImpl.validate(ConnectorImpl.java:350)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.ra.processors.ParsedRaDeploymentProcessor.process(ParsedRaDeploymentProcessor.java:187)
    ... 7 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was adding ra.xml to jars META-INF directory instead of rar META-INF directory. Adding to rar's META-INF directory solved the problem.